# Having trouble with the command 'pip install goeey'

Tags: python, pip

i wrote a python program that uses gooey.. it runs 100% find on my mac in pycharm, now im trynna run it on my windows and i am getting this error:

```
from gooey import Gooey. GooeyParser
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gooey'
```

so natrually i did:

```
pip install Gooey
```

then i get this error:

https://pastebin.com/5jnJzfXz

Comment: Please post the relevant error messages as part of your question.

Comment: @GinoMempin edited the post and pasted the imp messages!

Comment: Do you have a version of Microsoft Visual Studio installed?  That package needs to compile C++ code.

Comment: yes i have it installed and I launch terminal through that and type pip install gooey, still get an error @TimRoberts

Comment: and when i try to run "pip install gooey" through the Microsoft windows build tools terminal I get this error: "ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: " followed by a bunch of BS @TimRoberts

Comment: It has to be Visual Studio 2019 for some reason ("14.2").  Is that what you have?

Answer (score 1):

## Build tools fix

1. For your build tools problem, try to install build tools manually through this [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XzilA.png).
2. After that you have to restart your PC or laptop.
3. Then try `pip install Gooey`. If you have `3.x` version python, use `pip3`.

---

## Alternative Solution

You can try this

**1.** In Pycharm, go to `File -> settings -> Project:untitled1 (untitled1 means your project name) -> select project interpretor -> click add button`

[image]

**2.** after clicking add button and **search** `<package name>` then **install** it.

**3.** finally, run the program.

---

**Newer versions of Pycharm have a "`+`" mark (add button) here.**

[image]